# Elements over transcendental extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, soft-question, extension-field

Let $F$ a field and suppose that $E$ is a extension field of $F$. Now, take $\alpha\in E$ trascendental over $F$. My question is about the form of the elements of $F(\alpha)$. I think that $$F(\alpha)=\left\{\frac{f(\alpha)}{g(\alpha)}:f,g\in F[x]\right\}$$.

Am I right?

Comment: I think you meant "transcendental over $F$".  As to your collection, it isn't clear what you mean.  If $f,g\in F[x]$ then $\lambda f, \lambda g$ define the same element of $F(\alpha)$.  And if you allow multiple expressions for the same element then your collection defines $F(\alpha)$ even if $\alpha $ is algebraic.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are correct.

$F(\alpha)$ is defined to be the field of rational polynomials in $\alpha$ with coefficients in $F$.

You can also think about $F(\alpha)$ as being isomorphic to $F(t)$, the field of rational functions (the evaluation mapping at $\alpha$ serves as this isomorphism between transcendental elements and indeterminates), and $F(t)$ clearly has this form.